# Swift: Compute equation within String and convert to Int

Tags: string, swift, parsing, equation

I have been wondering for far too long now: Is it possible in any way to convert a String containing an equation to Int?

For example, this is what I tried:

```
var equation: String? = "\(5) \(+) \(8)" // 5, +, and 8 would be generated Ints/operaters

if let answer = Int(equation) {
    print("\(answer)")
}
```

I've been trying to find a way to do this across various languages with no luck. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're looking for an arithmetic expression evaluator, which isn't trivial to do and there doesn't exist a simple function that just does it. You can try to find an open-source implementation of a simple one.

EDIT: Have a look at the [Arithmetic Evaluation Rosetta Code page](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Arithmetic_evaluation), which is the simplest thing you probably want. There isn't a Swift version (yet), but you should be able to do it yourself by looking at the other languages.

Another EDIT: Check out [this Code Golf Thread](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/617/advanced-calculator) which features some of the shortest arithmetic expression evaluators in some languages (no Swift yet)

Last EDIT: Also have a look at the [Shunting-yard algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) and generalised [Operator-precedence parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator-precedence_parser). I'm actually very attempted now to write a simple one in Swift...

Post last EDIT: [There exists a Swift library for that :D](https://github.com/davedelong/DDMathParser/wiki/Usage). Also: Downvotes are for non-useful answers (see hover text), not for when there's a better answer (see comments)

Comment: Dear god just use `NSExpression`.

Comment: @robmayoff I did not know that, but thanks for mentioning. However I'm more and more trying to avoid `Foundation` and doing stuff more functional and in "pure" Swift, would love to see such a solution.

Comment: @robmayoff Note that downvotes aren't for answers that don't 100% answer the question, but rather for (as the hover text says): "This answer is not useful". And I truly do believe that this answer is useful in some way for at least future searchers. Probably you should post an answer with `NSExpression` because it's definitely worth one.

Comment: My answer about `NSExpression` is linked above, from my comment on the question.